# Syntax error possibly due to multiple ANDs?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE bookings b
SET reservation_processed = 'archived'
  JOIN reservation_time_data r ON r.id = b.reservation_time
WHERE premises_code = 'LJJIDHhRN2ho1e3h'
 AND reservation_date LIKE '%2020-09-10%'
 AND CURRENT_TIME > ADDTIME(r.end_time, '0:30:0.000000')
```

I first got the error in php, and I then tested it in phpmyadmin and I get an error. It doesn't specify why there is an error it just saying an error with the syntax. I thought it maybe because there is multiple AND clauses but I put them in brackets to maybe simplify it but it didn't help :( Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That UPDATE JOIN syntax isn't portable.)

Comment: @jarlh MySQL, I have used an update query before with a JOIN and it worked

Comment: PS. JOIN clause is a part of data source - so it must be placed in UPDATE clause but before SET clause. PPS. If data source contains more than one table then add table alias to EACH column name.

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html for multi-table syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE bookings b JOIN
       reservation_time_data r 
       ON r.id = b.reservation_time
    SET reservation_processed = 'archived'
WHERE premises_code = 'LJJIDHhRN2ho1e3h' AND
      reservation_date LIKE '%2020-09-10%' AND
      CURRENT_TIME > ADDTIME(r.end_time, '0:30:0.000000')
```

That said, your query should qualify *all* column references.  You can still get an invalid time.  Also, using `LIKE` on a date/column is *wrong*.  So is storing a date as a string.  If I assume that the value is really a date and speculate on where columns come from, then the query should look something like this:

```
UPDATE bookings b JOIN
       reservation_time_data r 
       ON r.id = b.reservation_time
    SET b.reservation_processed = 'archived'
WHERE b.premises_code = 'LJJIDHhRN2ho1e3h' AND
      r.reservation_date = '2020-09-10' AND
      CURRENT_TIME > ADDTIME(r.end_time, '0:30:0.000000')
```